# Getting blank white screen when presenting MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Anybody have trouble with an MPMoviePlayerViewController giving a white screen when it is presented?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath {  
MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
[[mpViewController moviePlayer] setContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://burtonliftline.com/site-media/uploads/videos/ad_to_fakie-the_liftline_1.mp4"]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're just seeing the blank controller while the movie is loading. Have you tried setting the view controller's background to black?

`[mpViewController setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing but my problem was that my video wasnt wanting to play on the iPhone from the server. It was shooting me this error when I tried to stream that video from safar "the server is not correctly configured". I needed to be pointing to http://media.burtonliftline.com/site-media/uploads/videos/ad_to_fakie-the_liftline_1.mp4